# Splicing JSON object from array

Tags: javascript, json, object, splice

I have tried splicing my json file using a for loop
JSON file:

```
[
   {
     "name":"Billy Jean",
     "age":"52",
     "sex":"F",
     },
     {
     "name":"Bob Semple",
     "age":"32",
     "sex":"M",
     } there are more....
]
```

What I have tried (i imported it and called it contactList)

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < contactList.length ; i++){
   if(contactlist.age > 40) {
         contactList.splice(i, 1);
     }
}
```

if i run the code and check the output nothing changes in my JSON file

Comment: are you looking to filter the array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new array using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

- Notice that `age` property it's of type `string` and should be compared as `number` using [unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator

Code:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Billy Jean",
    "age": "52",
    "sex": "F",
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob Semple",
    "age": "32",
    "sex": "M",
  }
]

const result = data.filter(({ age }) => +age > 40)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: understandable, it works.
does the filtering work if i used a for loop and get the index of i?

Comment: You can get the `index` for all the filtered elements within `filter` function and do something with that.. e.g. add them to an array